# Merge dxf files from multiple pages into one page

Tags: python, pdf, merge, dxf, ezdxf

I tried to merge multiple dxf files into one dxf file.

I've used Importer of [ezdxf](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/addons/importer.html) (Python package) but the result was that dxf files were accumulated in layers on one page.

```
def merge(source, target):
    try:
        source = ezdxf.readfile(source)

    except ezdxf.DXFError as e:
        print("DXF file not found")
        return False

    try:
        importer = Importer(source, target)
        importer.import_modelspace()
        importer.finalize()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: ", e.__class__)
```

This is the input dxf files:
[image]

[image]

This is the current output dxf file:
[image]

The result I want is continuous dxf files on one page like following:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Always thanks for your information, K J. This gives me another way to try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the **KJ**'s comment.
This worked for me and I just need to adjust the translation amount in the `y-axis`.

`transform.inplace(sdoc.modelspace(), Matrix44.translate(0, index * 0, 0))`

Please check this official `ezdxf` doc about combining multiple dxf files.
https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/xref_module.html#load-modelspace